# Using Excel commands in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Please look at the image.-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERues.jpg)

Suppose I have two columns X and Y in Excel In the third column I want to identify those numbers which are in column 1 but not in column 2. How do I write such a script in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on it here:

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-excel-tutorial

This has everything I believe you need for what you want to do.